# Is there a setting to limit cgi processes by real time on Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2

I'd like Apache to terminate my perl script after 1 minute if it doesn't complete naturally. Is there a setting in Apache (or other server software) to do this?

Answer (score 1):

[CGIwrap](http://cgiwrap.sourceforge.net/) does much of the stuff that suEXEC does (run the script under alternate permissions), but it also allows you to set resource limits:

```
--with-rlimit-cpu=SECONDS
    limit cpu time with setrlimit
--with-rlimit-vmem=BYTES
    limit total virtual memory with setrlimit
--with-rlimit-as=BYTES
    limit total available memory with setrlimit
--with-rlimit-fsize=BYTES
    limit writable file size with setrlimit
--with-rlimit-data=BYTES
    limit data segment size with setrlimit
--with-rlimit-stack=BYTES
    limit stack segment size with setrlimit
--with-rlimit-core=BYTES
    limit core file size with setrlimit
--with-rlimit-rss=BYTES
    limit resident set size with setrlimit
--with-rlimit-nproc=COUNT
    limit number of processes with setrlimit
--with-rlimit-nofile=COUNT
    limit number of open files with setrlimit
--with-rlimit-memlock=BYTES
    limit lockable memory with setrlimit
```

Answer (score 0):

Of the top of my head I can see two solutions (NOTE: I am a UNIX/Linux guy):

1. Make modifications to your perl code to set an alarm and then program a signal processor to capture the alarm and perform whatever processing you want.
2. You could manipulate the CPU limit of a process to terminate if it gets to 1 second CPU time.  However, that real clock time length to get to 1 second of CPU time depends on your perl script.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=703780

Answer (score 0):

You could always put "alarm 60;" at the top of your Perl scripts.  However, this would require modifying all your Perl programs.